# IPv6 configuration: ISP is blocking Neighbor Discovery

Tags: ipv6, isp

My ISP offers IPv6 to interested customers, but doesn't provide any support in this regard.

I've been given a /64 prefix (let's call it 2345:6789:11:22::/64), a gateway address (2345:6789:11:22::1) and two DNS server addresses by tech support. They told me I have to use static IPs and recommended that I use 2345:6789:11:22:1:: for my home network (but I suppose there's nothing stopping me from using whatever I want on that subnet). I've been using 2345:6789:11:22::2/64 (and also 2345:6789:11:22:1::2/64, for that matter) for my OpenWrt router's WAN interface which is plugged into my DSL modem.

I was told that they've blocked Neighbor Discovery Protocol (NDP) because of problems with Windows Vista clients generating a lot of traffic. Sure enough, Wireshark (running on a firewall-less Linux box plugged directly into the DSL modem) shows no replies to Neighbor/Router Solicitation messages.

As an aside, tech support told me that, in general, when running IPv6, the default gateway will always be equal to **prefix**::1, but as far as I can tell, this is not part of the spec, but just convention (similar to how 192.168.1.1 tends to be the default gateway in IPv4, but could just as well be, say, 192.168.13.37).

As for the IPv4 Internet connection, my router immediately gets an IP via DHCP, and I'm online. No problems there.

The IPv6 connection, however, is unable to even connect to the upstream gateway, as evidenced by the following tests:

- ping6 gateway 2345:6789:11:22::1 (or indeed any non-local IP): no replies
- traceroute6 any IPv6 address: never gets past my home network

According to tech support, the DSL modem doesn't filter any traffic whatsoever.

Pinging my Linux box (static IP: 2345:6789:11:22::3/64) from my OpenWrt routers WAN interface (2345:6789:11:22::2/64) works perfectly. While I was doing this, I was on the phone with tech support who told me to plug my OpenWrt router into the DSL modem, and strangely, he was able to briefly see these ICMPv6 packets (sent from my router to my Linux box) on his end. He was using tcpdump. What could be the reason for this? He was able to see no other IPv6 traffic coming from my DSL line.

Additionally, Wireshark (running on my Linux box) shows that no ping6 messages get through from tech support to my Linux box or to my router, even when plugged directly into the DSL modem.

The tech support guy finally insisted that there are no problems on their end. Apparently, several of their customers have fully-functioning IPv6 Internet connections. He suggested that the problems might be caused by inappropriate iptables rules on my equipment, but I've since excluded this possibility (since the Kali Linux live USB I was running on my Linux Box comes with a fully open firewall, i.e. with no iptables rules).

How can I conclusively prove to tech support that the problem doesn't lie with my configuration (or find out that it actually does)?

Comment: Either the ISP is doing something terribly wrong, or there is some critical information missing here. Possibly both. For instance, there is nothing here about how to configure your WAN interface.

Comment: Not sure I understand what information is missing regarding the WAN interface. I was told to assign the static IP 2345:6789:11:22::2/64 and the gateway 2345:6789:11:22::1 to my router's WAN interface. This should enable the router to ping upstream hosts, right?

Comment: Right, but that doesn't leave you any addresses for the LAN! It also doesn't tell your router where to route outgoing traffic.

Comment: I'm still new to IPv6, so apologies if I'm asking stupid questions. Could you explain why that doesn't leave me any addresses for the LAN? Also, I assumed outgoing traffic would be routed through the gateway. Is that not the case? Thanks for taking the time to help me, much appreciated.

Comment: I see what you mean. LAN and WAN should be on different subnets, but I used up the entire /64 on the WAN interface, so there's nothing left to distribute to the LAN. I assume I could solve this by using two different /80 subnets for the WAN and LAN? But then the gateway address (2345:6789:11:22::1) would take on a different meaning and refer to a different host, right (2345:6789:11:22::1/64 being different from 2345:6789:11:22::1/80)?

Comment: No, you do not further subnet a /64. That is one network, period. Your ISP should have given you more space than that.